# A native sdk function to scale Bitmap?

Tags: android, graphics

Is there some native android SDK function which takes bitmap and desired new bitmap dimensions and then returns scaled bitmap?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might take a look at: `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() corrupts the image. I think it changes the encoding to RGB_565, which means that the resulting bitmap is useless garbage.